# Why can't I create an unordered access view of a R32G32B32_UINT buffer?

Tags: directx11

So I'm trying to create an unordered access view for a buffer having with three component elements, but it fails with this warning:

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateUnorderedAccessView:
The format (0x7, R32G32B32_UINT) cannot be used with a Typed Unordered Access View.
[ STATE_CREATION ERROR #2097343: CREATEUNORDEREDACCESSVIEW_INVALIDFORMAT].
```

This is my code:

```
void test(ID3D11Device* dev_ctx) {
  D3D11_BUFFER_DESC buff_desc;
  memset(&buff_desc, 0, sizeof(buff_desc));

  buff_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS;
  buff_desc.ByteWidth = 1024 * 12;
  buff_desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
  buff_desc.MiscFlags = 0;
  buff_desc.StructureByteStride = 12;
  buff_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

  ID3D11Buffer* buff_ptr = nullptr;
  dev_ctx->CreateBuffer(&buff_desc, nullptr, &buff_ptr);

  if (!buff_ptr)
    return;

  D3D11_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC uav_desc;
  uav_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_UINT;
  uav_desc.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
  uav_desc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
  uav_desc.Buffer.Flags = 0;
  uav_desc.Buffer.NumElements = 1024;

  ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* uav_ptr = nullptr;
  dev_ctx->CreateUnorderedAccessView(buff_ptr, &uav_desc, &uav_ptr);

  if (!uav_ptr)
    return;
  }
```

It fails for any resource with three components (`R32G32B32_*`), but it works
if the resource has 1/2/4 components. So what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is basically spelled out for you in the error message: Direct3D does not support the use of the `R32G32B32_UINT` format in a typed UAV. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471325(v=vs.85).aspx) has a section on supported formats for typed UAVs. `R32G32B32_UINT` is not on the list.

Comment: Thank you, I see now. It's unfortunate that this information is buried in the DXGI section. At least they could have put a link to it in the CreateUnorderedAccessView() entry.

Comment: Make sure you read up on Direct3D [Feature Levels](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels.aspx).